# How to create custom keyboard shortcuts in vim?

Tags: linux, unix, vim, text-editors, gvim

For example - when coding in Perl, I need to sometimes comment out a bunch of lines.

- What I do is something like

  ```
  :80,96 s/^\(.*\)$/#\1/
  ```
- I want to create a custom shortcut for this so that I can do something like

  ```
  :80,96 cm
  ```

  for commenting and

  ```
  :80,96 uc
  ```

  for uncommenting.

What should I put in my `~/.vimrc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a pair commands, like this:

```
command -range Cm <line1>,<line2>s/^/#/
command -range Uc <line1>,<line2>s/^#//
```

Note that a user-defined command must start with an upper-case letter.  See

```
:help :command
:help user-commands
```

There is also a Vim plugin that many people use for this, [Enhanced Commentify](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=23), but I don't have any experience with it myself.