# MacVim-like keyboard shortcuts in gVim

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vim, gvim, macvim

MacVim has some nifty features like Cmd + S to save Cmd + Z to undo, and so on, is there a port like this for gVim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the **map** command in your **.vimrc** (or **_vimrc** in windows) like this (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> to save):

```
map <C-S> :w <CR>
map! <C-S> <ESC> :W <CR> i
```

The later is for when you are in **insert mode**. You can find more information here [Mapping Keys](http://newbiedoc.sourceforge.net/text_editing/vim.html.en#MAPPING-VIM)

Answer (score 0):

These shortcuts are not standard vim shortcuts. However, undo is simply "u" and save ":w" (after entering the right mode with ESC).

See eg. [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/190105/how-to-create-custom-keyboard-shortcuts-in-vim) on how to create your own shortcuts.